# Как получить информацию из alert

Tags: javascript

Мне нужно получить информацию, выдаваемую в `alert` + `prompt` и занести её в `js` скрипт.
Не знаю с какой стороны подступиться.

Коротко о ситуации: некий сайт выдает мне `prompt(семь + 2 = (поле для ввода))`,
мне нужно получить текст, вписать ответ в поле и нажать ОК.

Comment: вообще ничего не понятно. Если имеются ввиду нативные prompt и alert - то ты хочешь невозможного, так как это _блокирующие_ диалоги, и пока они показываются - все скрипты остановлены

Comment: Вам нужно получать информацию не из alert/prompt, а из того скрипта, который её туда заносит.

Comment: Измените ваш вопрос. В javascript нет никаких alarm'ов, есть только alert'ы.